# Ruby Premature EOF?

Tags: ruby, base64, eof

I'm trying to write one file *into* another one in Ruby, but the output seems to stop prematurely.

Input file - large CSS file with base64 embedded fonts

Output file - basic html file.

```
#write some HTML before the CSS (works)
...
#write the external CSS (doesn't work, output finished prematurely)
while !ext_css_file.eof()        
    out_file.puts(ext_css_file.read())
end
...
#write some HTML after the CSS (works)
```

The resulting file is basically a valid HTML file, with a truncated CSS (in the middle of an embedded font)

When doing a puts on the result of read(), I get the same result: The CSS file is read only up to this last string: "RMSHhoPCAGt/mELDBESFBQSggGfAgESKCUAAAAAAAwAlgABAAAAAAABAAUADAABAAAAAAAC"

Comment: not sure if puts/read/eof work so well together. Have you tried reading the file into a string and then writing it as a string? Or alternatively: Use read/write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a detailed solution without more insight into what the CSS file actually contains.  Based on your code above, I would try something like this instead:

```
#write some HTML before the CSS (works)
...
#write the external CSS (doesn't work, output finished prematurely)
out_file.puts(ext_css_file.read())
...
#write some HTML after the CSS (works)
```

I don't think you need the `.eof` check because the `read` method reads and returns the entire file contents, or an empty string or nil if at the end of file.  See here: http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/read

I would tend to read and write the same type of data.  For instance if I were writing data into the new file using `puts`, I would read data using `readlines`.  If I were writing binary data using `write`, I would read the data using `read`.  I would be consistent with either strings or bytes and not mix the two.

Try something like this...

```
File.open('writable_file_path', 'w') do |f|
  # f.puts "some html"
  f.puts IO.readlines('css_file_path')
  # f.puts "some more html"
end
```